# Multiline string not aligning properly with ax.annotate

Tags: matplotlib, annotations

I have a multiline string as below

```
annotation_string = """Excel file name: {0}
        Sheet name: {1}
        
        No.of Iterations: {2}
        Cp = {3}
        CpK = {4}
        
        Mean = {11}
        Standard Deviation = {12}
        
        The smallest simulated value is {5}
        The largest simulated value is {6}
        
        The 4sigma limit is from {7} to {8}
        The 5sigma limit is from {9} to {10}
        """.format(filename,sheet,iterations,round(cp,4),round(cpk,4),smallest_val,
                  largest_val,round(mean_minor_sigma[3],5),round(mean_sigma[3],5),
                   round(mean_minor_sigma[4],5),round(mean_sigma[4],5),round(mittelwert,4),round(sigma,4))
```

I use the code below to plot this on an axis on a plot

```
        ax1.annotate(annotation_string, xy=(0.65, 0.65), xycoords='axes fraction',
                                                     backgroundcolor='r', fontsize=14,
                                                     horizontalalignment='left')
```

The result is as the pic below. AS you can see the text from 2nd line onwards has shifted right.

[image]

However, when I change `horizontalalignment='left'` to `horizontalalignment='right'`. Every line is aligned properly

[image]

I want the alignment to the left & not to the right. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the way to have the alignment properly, the updated code below.
No change in the 'plot' code at all. Only change in the formulation on multiline text.

**Note:-** Apparently the '' after the triple quotes at the beginning is important (don't know why but without it, the output was as before)

```
import textwrap
annotation_string = textwrap.dedent("""\
        Excel file name: {0}
        Sheet name: {1}
        
        No.of Iterations: {2}
        Cp = {3}
        CpK = {4}
        
        Mean = {11}
        Standard Deviation = {12}
        
        The smallest simulated value is {5}
        The largest simulated value is {6}
        
        The 4sigma limit is from {7} to {8}
        The 5sigma limit is from {9} to {10}
        """).format(filename,sheet,millify(iterations),round(cp,4),round(cpk,4),smallest_val,largest_val,round(mean_minor_sigma[3],5),round(mean_sigma[3],5),round(mean_minor_sigma[4],5),round(mean_sigma[4],5),round(mittelwert,4),round(sigma,4))
```